# installing fastkde library in Python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to install fastkde library and I did actually everything on web but I am yet able to install this. I constantly get this error in terminal:

```
Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-4ff4dzcb/fastkde/
```

Can anybody help me with this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you've `pip` installed which is true for all distributions downloaded from [here](https://python.org/), then just key in the commands in your terminal given below.

```
pip3 install fastkde
```

Comment: Unfortunately did not work, it says: Requirement already satisfied: fastkde in ./anaconda3/lib/python3.5/site-packages

Comment: Then you already have it installed, try `import fastkde` to see if it works.

Comment: I am using pycharm, it says to when I used import fastkde and then gave this:
Collecting fastkde
  Using cached fastkde-1.0.10.tar.gz
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/tmp/pycharm-packaging/fastkde/setup.py", line 2, in <module>
        from Cython.Build import cythonize
    ImportError: No module named 'Cython'

Comment: Cython is a dependancy, you'd need to install it too.

Comment: Thanks, that helped!

Comment: Happy to help mate!